# JS not executed after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a small weather app. On the front end, I have a search bar and whenever the user type something, I am loading a list of cities that match with the value of the user input and ordered by population with a limit of 10.

This functionality is now working: a `ul` of `li` cities in generated.

Now it seems my `app.js` is locked on the `AJAX`, I am trying to add an event listener for every `li` elements `onclick` but it does not execute at all. Seems that it has to due with async / sync.

**index.php**

```
<body>
    <?php require_once("config/db.php")?>
    <h2>Weather</h2>
    <input type="text" name="city-search" class="city-search" id="city-search">
    <ul class="result f32">
  ...
</ul>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
const search = document.querySelector("#city-search");
const results = document.querySelector(".result");
const listCities = document.querySelectorAll(".cities-select");


// works
search.addEventListener("keyup", e =>{
    let city = search.value;
    if(city != ""){
        loadCities(city);
    }
});


// works
const loadCities = (city) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "config/fetch-cities.php",
        method: "GET",
        async: true,
        data: {
            query: city
        },
        success: function(data){
            results.innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}

// does not execute 
listCities.forEach(city => {
    city.addEventListener("click", e =>{
        console.log("hello world");
    })
})
```

**fetch.php**

```
<?php 
require("db.php");

if(isset($_GET["query"])){
    $search = $_GET["query"];
    $results = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '{$search}%' 
    ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 5");
} 

$results->execute();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<li class="cities-select">
     <div> '.$row["city"].' </div>
     <div> '.$row["country"].' </div>
     </li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the browser frozen, aka the tab crashes, and most browsers will ask you if you want to terminate the related script, or does the code simply not execute? That's kind of a huge difference.

Comment: @James you are trying to iterate what? $.ajax() will not return to `loadCities` nothing that can be iterated.

Comment: I will change my question to "code simply not execute"

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, you are calling `addEventListener` before `.cities-select` exists (you load the page -> tries to loop over `.cities-select` but it doesn't exist). You need to add your event listeners in your `$.Ajax#success` function, after you have set `.innerHTML`.

```js
const search = document.querySelector("#city-search");
const results = document.querySelector(".result");

// works
search.addEventListener("keyup", e =>{
    let city = search.value;
    if(city != ""){
        loadCities(city);
    }
});


// works
const loadCities = (city) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "config/fetch-cities.php",
        method: "GET",
        async: true,
        data: {
            query: city
        },
        success: function(data){
            results.innerHTML = data;
            const cities = document.querySelectorAll(".cities-select");
            cities.forEach(city => {
                city.addEventListener("click", e =>{
                    console.log("hello world");
                })
            })
        }
    });
}
```